# How to make view slide onto screen?

Tags: android

I want to make a horizontal LinearLayout that has a portion off screen slide onto the screen when it is dragged, using `horizontalLayout.setX()`, but when the layout is dragged the views in that layout that were off the screen don't seem to appear on screen, and they seem to be cut off by the screen edge. What would be the best way to achieve this? Can a view not be created off the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understood properly but..why don't you just use a horizontal scroll view?